# Will I incur sins if I stand in prayer even though my wudhu is broken?

Tags: salat, wudu, jamaat

Suppose I'm praying an obligatory prayer behind an Imam at a masjid. Suddenly my wudhu breaks (due to the passing of wind).

Now, if I still keep standing in prayer will I incur sins?

[This should help you in answering the question.](https://islamqa.info/en/141613)

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intentionally go ahead with a prayer that is invalid you will certainly be sinning, some scholars even discussed whether this is an act that makes you a kafir or not!
Why kafir? Because this person knows the ruling an nevertheless goes against it this is a meaning of kufr in Arabic which is also used in the Qur'an.

> قال النووي رحمه الله: إن كان عالما بالحدث وتحريم الصلاة مع الحدث فقد ارتكب معصيةً عظيمةً، ولا يكفر عندنا بذلك، إلا أن يستحله، وقال أبو حنيفة: يكفر لاستهزائه.
> دليلنا : أنه معصية فأشبهت الزنا وأشباهه
>
> Imam an-Nawawi said (in [his al-Majmu' المجموع شرح المهذب](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=694&bk_no=14&flag=1) Vol. 2 page 78-79) If he knows that he is impure and that it is haraam to pray when one is impure, then he has committed a grave sin, but he does not become a kaafir thereby in our view, unless he regards that as permissible. But Abu Haneefah said: He has committed kufr because of his disrespect.
> Our evidence is that it is a sin so it is akin to zina and the like.
> (Source of the translation islamqa #[65731](https://islamqa.info/en/65731))

And from the sunnah:

> It was narrated from ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “It was ordered that one of the slaves of Allaah be flogged in his grave with one hundred lashes, but he kept asking until it was reduced to a single blow. So he was given a single blow, then his grave was filled with fire. When he came round, he said: ‘Why did you flog me?’ It was said to him: ‘You offered one prayer without being taahir, and you passed by one who was being wronged and did not help him.’” Narrated by al-Tahhaawi in Mushkil al-Athaar, 4/231; classed as hasan by al-Albaani in  al-Silsilah al-Saheehah, 2774.  (Source of the translation islamqa #[65731](https://islamqa.info/en/65731))

A prayer without taharah is invalid due to ahadith such as:

> "Allah does not accept prayer of anyone of you if he does Hadath (passes wind) till he performs the ablution (anew). (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/90/2))

On the whole this is an act of disrespect of the rulings of Allah and therefore it is clearly a big sin. And one should repent from this and (of course) re-do this prayer as it is clearly invalid.
If one does so by mistake or unintentionally and find out he only needs to re-do this prayer.

My major references:
Fatwas (in Arabic) islamweb #[241816](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=241816) , #[167217](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=167217), #[115529](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=115529) and imam an-Nawawi's al-Majmo'.